# Assigning multiple participant roles in civi event, through imports

Tags: civievent, roles, data-import

I would like to assign multiple roles to event participants through imports.
I can upload a csv to assign a user role, but if I import a second data source with a different role, it is set aside as a duplicate and not imported. I would like the second role to be added to the existing record (not to be overwritten).

For instance I have a list of auction event participants who are attendees, donors and/or buyers. My lists have overlapping contacts.  I would like to keep these all associated with the event, rather than creating groups or tags. Handling the overlaps manually is not practical.

Comment: can you import with comma within the one field separating the various 
 role IDs

Comment: That DOES work, which is great BUT it means that all roles need to be established and merged before any importing.  I want to be able to import three different data sets and let the roles accumulate, partly because the roles are established at different times. Someone may be a VIP guest BEFORE the event.  Afterwards, I want to add the role of "Buyer". Thanks for your suggestion. I feel like it gets me one step closer.

Answer (score 0):

The value for all Role data is stored in a single field so I think however you tackle this you are at risk of overwriting existing Roles. Here is one process that at least makes existing Role values visible so you won't overwrite them accidentally.

Create a Profile for updating Participants that includes the Import your Contact IDs and add them to a Group

Use Adv Search to find those Contacts but set the search "Display Results As" to be Participants.

Select the records you want to update - under Actions choose Update multiple participants - select the Profile you created above - this should then give you a batch updates screen where each Role is shown as a checkbox

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I could do a batch update of adding a role, is that the idea?  I had hoped there would have been a simpler solution, similar to adding tags to an import, where they just continue to build in the record.  I think that reverting to using tags for my roles might end up being the simplest solution, though I'm afraid I'll end up with tag tangles.

Comment: Yes my suggestion was using Batch Updating and the only extra work that I see compared to Adding Tags, is the fact that it is a checkbox field and therefore if you have a mix of current roles you won't be able to use the photocopy button at the top. Have you thought about using custom fields instead? One field for each 'role' and then use Batch Updating where you would be able to use the photocopy button.